# Skipping indexes in Python?

Tags: python, list, loops

I am basically trying to iterate over a list of 12 values and if a value at a specific index (every third) is also a value in a dictionary I want to append that corresponding key to a new list.
ps is a list with 12 values. dict is a dictionary also with 12 keys and values.

```
ps = [57.06, 98.74, 83.3, 77.24, 63.59, 101.11, 83.2, 90.67, 85.12, 72.28, 
86.16, 92.56]

list1=[]            
count=0
while count<10:
      for key, value in dict.items():
         if value ==ps[count]:  
            list1.append(key)
            count=count+3
```

I get an "index out of range" error. The code works if I type "while count<6". As soon as it is above 6 it doesn't work, which I don't understand as the list has 11 indexes.

Any help would be much appreciated.

The code fails at "if value ==ps[count]:"

Comment: Could you show us what the list `ps` is?

Comment: On which line is it failing? Also, can you show us what's in ps?

Comment: `list1 = [k for k, v in dict.items() if v in ps[::3]]`…?!

Comment: I tried this code and it works, but it adds the values to the list in the order (6,0,3,9). Is there a way to fix this so they are in the order (0,3,6,9)?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that your for loop is within the while loop, so it will finish the for loop completely before checking the while condition again.

To fix this you could instead do:

```
  list1=[]            
  count=0
  for key, value in dict.items():
      if count <10:
         if value == ps[count]:  
            list1.append(key)
            count=count+3
```

or, as @deceze has said

```
list_1 = [k for k, v in dict.items() if v in ps[::3]]
```

since ps[::3] is the list of every 3rd element of ps

Comment: Oh I see, didn't think of that, I tried the code you suggest and it works for index 0 and 3 but then stops. So the count needs to go to 9. Can't quite fugure out why it works for 2 iterations but not 4

Answer (score 1):

Here's how it may fail:

```
for key, value in dict.items():
    if value == ps[count]:  
        list1.append(key)
        count=count+3
```

1. Begin the loop above (iteration 0; count == 0)
2. Enter `if` statement, increase `count`
3. Begin the next iteration (iteration 1; count == 3)
4. Enter `if` statement, increase `count`
5. Begin the next iteration (iteration 2; count == 6)
6. Enter `if` statement, increase `count`
7. Begin the next iteration (iteration 3; count == 9)
8. Enter `if` statement, increase `count`
9. Begin the next iteration (iteration 4; count == 12)
10. Enter `if` statement, increase `count`
11. Begin the next iteration (iteration 5; count == 15)
12. *AND ON AND ON IT GOES!*
13. At some point `count` becomes greater or equal to the length of `ps`, and you get the error

Why? Because `dict.items()` may contain a quadrillion elements, and while iterating over them you're increasing `count` *and not checking it* because that whole loop is still *the first iteration* of the outer `while` loop.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your `while` loop, you increment count by 3, so your condition is satisfied for `count = 0, 3, 6, 9`, basically 4 iterations.
If you want to iterate over a given range, I recommend you use a `for` loop which lets you specify the `step_size`
`for count in range(0, 10, 3):`

If you wan to iterate over all elements, you simply adjust the `step_size`

Comment: That's a good idea, I was not sure how to do that. Do you know how I can implement this code since I then have 2 "for" loops?